# Python exec() fails to initialize a class instance in a function

Tags: python, class, initialization, exec

I want to **initialize a class instance in a function by using "exec()", then return the instance**. But it doesn't works, although I have added "globals()" in the parameters of "exec()" function. Here is my code:

```
>>> class Foo:
        def __init__(self):
            print("hello world")


>>> def initialize():
        fooInstance = None
        exec('fooInstance = Foo()', globals())
        print(fooInstance)
        return fooInstance

>>> test = initialize()
hello world
None

>>> print(test)
None
```

Basically, the "**init**" function of the class is called, but the variable "**fooInstance**" is **NOT** changed to a Foo's object, keeps "None" value.

I also tested if using exec() to initialize a class instance in outer scope works, and the answer is YES.

```
>>> newInstance = None
>>> exec('newInstance = Foo()', globals())
hello world
>>> newInstance
<__main__.Foo object at 0x00000273AF151F60>
```

I would appreciate if any solutions to initialize it **in a function** by using "exec()".

Comment: Have you tried `global fooInstance` instead of `fooInstance = None` in your `initialize()` function?

Comment: Thanks Xay, it works now! That's probably because `exec` takes `globals()` parameter when it is a global variable (in outer scope) or explicitly defined as `global`